# Prove that $\lim_{k\to \infty} x_{n_{k}} = c$ for any subsequence $x_{n_{k}}$ of $(x_n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

**Question:** Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n} = c$. Prove that $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_{n_{k}} = c$ for any subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})$ of $(x_{n})$. [Hint: $n_{k} \geq k$.]

Could you please help me how can I prove it can I use the following definition ?

**Definition:** 
Let $(n_{k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers; that is, $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \dotsb$ . If $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence, then $(x_{n_{k}})_{k=1}^{\infty} = (x_{n_{1}},x_{n_{2}},x_{n_{3}},\dotsc)$ is called a subsequence of $(x_n)$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then by assumption there is some $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|x_{n}-c| < \varepsilon$. If $(x_{n_{k}})$ is a subsequence of $(x_{n})$, then there is some $K$ sch that $n_{K} \geq N$; so $|x_{n_{k}} - c| < \varepsilon$ for all $k \geq K$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT. $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=c$ iff  for every $r>0$ the set $\{n:x_n\not \in (-r+c,r+c)\}$ is finite.